# вырезать слово с стринга

Tags: c#

есть

```
string text = "{\"phone\":\"995555303481\",\"message\":{\"successful\":true,\"code\":0,\"errorText\":\"\",\"response\":0}}";
```

как вырезать отсюда номер **995555303481**

Comment: [JSON](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+JSON)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Как сериализировать и десериализировать JSON в .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0)

```cs
using System.Text.Json;
```

```cs
public class Response
{
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
string phone = JsonSerializer.Deserealize<Response>(text, options).Phone;
```