# Новая строчка после запятой C# CMD

Tags: c#

Всем привет у меня есть консольное приложение которое работает с API. В общем после получения информации в string у меня есть огромный текст в котором нужно сделать что бы после каждой запятой был перенос на строку. Вопрос, как это сделать? На скриншоте показано как написан текст после получения. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем вам это? Это JSON, десериализуйте его и работайте с данными. Ну а если надо читаемый вид, то опять же, это JSON, десериализуйте его и сериализуйте обратно с указанием форматирования.

Comment: Зачем вам это?.

Comment: Извините я просто новичок, "десериализуйте его и сериализуйте обратно с указанием форматирования" это как?

Comment: [Как сериализировать и десериализировать JSON в .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0)

Comment: "Зачем вам это?. " хочу сделать для своих ребят из клана в игре Warface получение информации о игроке (например посмотреть статистику противника).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/736927/222542

Comment: @aepot А [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1305541/220553) почему не закрыто?

Comment: Ссылки в синем блоке над вопросом. Единственный нюанс, я рекомендую использовать новый встроенный JSON парсер `System.Text.Json`, как в моей ссылке выше в комментарии. Но смысл и логика десереализации JSON везде одинаковая, независимо от того, какой именно парсер вы выберете.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ мне показалось, там проще ответить в лоб, чем прогнать его через все круги десереализации. Щас закрою.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное)

Comment: Ну кстати проще ответить в лоб, потому что я еще не смог это сделать, но примерно понял смысл)

Comment: На будущее: не вставляйте текст в вопрос скриншотами, вставляйте текст текстом.

Comment: Хорошо, в следующий раз вставлю текст)